# Which would be the most accurate way for writing multiple queries in PHP / MySQL, and why?

Tags: php, mysql

Which would be the most accurate way for writing multiple queries in PHP / MySQL, and why? (The opinion should be backed up with facts and references)

The next example works ok, but I am concern if it is the most appropriate way, and which could be cons of doing it this way?

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_bd");

$query_1 = "SELECT product_name FROM products";
$result_1 = mysqli_query($con, $query_1) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($con), E_USER_ERROR); 

$query_2 = "SELECT user_name FROM users";
$result_2 = mysqli_query($con, $query_2) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($con), E_USER_ERROR); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1)) {
            echo $row['product_name']);
        }

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_2)) {
            echo $row['user_name']);
        }

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($con);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

(of course, this is just an example, queries are usualy much longer than these).

Comment: If the sets of data are not related, then use separate queries. However .. make sure to correctly handle resource management and errors.

Comment: Some food for thought, a couple of my projects I think are well-structured: [without a framework](https://github.com/halfer/php-tutorial-project) and [with a framework](https://github.com/halfer/awooga-app/) (Slim).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend @WAJ's answer but depending on your project it might be overkill.

A simple way to organize would be to make an object out of your queries.

It's only an example so you get an idea.

```
class Person {

    protected $username;
    protected $ID;

    public function setUsername($name)
    {
        $this->username = $name;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getUserID()...ETC

}

class PersonMapper
{
    public function getUser(Person $User)
    {

        //$User->getUsername() has the user's name, so we can fetch the ID here.

        $query_2 = "SELECT user_name FROM users";
        //...only get data here, no filtering, no validation. nothing more.
        //If you need to validate the data do it somewhere else or your code will be messy.


        //Fetch result into $row['user_id'] then do:
        $User->setUserID($row['user_id']);
        //You can fetch other information here and give all the information $User needs. I would fetch ALL of the information so you can have the information needed all the time.
        $User->setDateOfBirth(... ETC
    }
}
```

Call using:

```
$User = new Person();
$User->setUsername($_POST['username']); //Don't do this unless you want to get hacked. Filter your user data first! It's just an example.
$UserMapper = new PersonMapper();
$UserMapper->getUser($User);
echo $User->getUserID(); //Outputs the DB information.
```

See? No queries and is easy to read/reuse. When you have a problem with a query you'll know exactly where to look.

Do the same for other objects don't put everything under one class. Think of them as real world objects.

Have a different method for every query you have that's related to your main object.

`class Products`

`class ProductMapper`

...but yeah, you get the idea.

Comment: I see your point in OOP style. But how would you approach this issue with procedural style?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is fine for very small projects. Once projects get bigger you will need an organizational pattern and ideally a mechanism to generate SQL for you. I would suggest setting up a Model and Controller pattern. Your controllers will contain the logic and call on your models to run queries and return the result.

Keeping these separate makes queries in the models reusable in multiple controllers and easier to debug. You will gain the benefit of having dynamically generated queries and it becomes much less work to fix issues and add security layers (query injection escaping) etc.

There are numerous MVC frameworks for PHP out there that are already set up to do this for you. For any medium to large sized project I would recommend using a framework. Here are a few PHP MVC frameworks:

- http://cakephp.org/
- http://www.codeigniter.com/
- http://laravel.com/

I would research which is the best for your project.

Comment: If I read the title of this question, it seems to be particularly about running queries (though I don't disagree with your broader answer, which is that a tidy internal architecture is a good thing). But let me say this anyway: one of the confusions I think some web frameworks have created is that using an ORM and an MVC-like library are indivisible.

Comment: I take the view that they are not: you can have a MVC-like system without an ORM (e.g. Slim) and an ORM without a framework (Propel, Doctrine, etc). This might be a case of Not Invented Here: frameworks should be using established ORMs rather than implementing their own.

Comment: Both of you are correct. I have removed the mention to an ORM from the question and just focus on suggesting an MVC. I guess in my mind I assume one comes with the other but this is not necessarily true. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Why the code in the example would only be good for small projects? What are the cons?

Comment: Imagine if your application needed hundreds of different queries. Then you realize that you need to do something to all of them or a group of them, such as escape input strings or apply formatting to the returned data. In your example you will need to modify the code for each of those hundreds of queries and while loops. If all queries go through the same app model layer then you will have one strategic place to apply logic to the entire system. The answer by @Tek is really good btw.

Answer (score 0):

1) It's a good practice to not send a new query to the server when you're not done fetching the first one.

2) I usually prefer to do all the query fetching and data processing before outputting HTML. This way if something crashes, the user doesn't get stuck with half a page, it's everything or nothing. It also keeps the code cleaner and easier to manage.

Comment: On your 2nd point, if you need to move around with 1 billion rows, your php code will crash in a second. Some content is better than nothing.

Comment: Agree on the second point, however, 1 billion rows is a lot and if it came to that, it would probably need to be handled in a different way than fetching all of them. I don't agree that some content is better than nothing, if the end user arrives on a blank page, he'll think it's a server issue, maybe maintenance. A half-page looks like a broken website.

Comment: A blank page shows a broken website. Half-page still shows a broken website, but at least there is content. And what matters in a webpage? It's the **content**.

Comment: I understand your point, however I still don't agree with it. Sending broken content to your users damages your credibility in my opinion. Not to mention that if there is a bug that's big enough to make the page crash, the content of the page might be erroneous.

Comment: The user goes to a blank page. It tells him nothing. The user won't even try again. He will just leave. The user comes to a page. There was an error and there was some content that he wanted. The user might try a few times to get the page right.

Answer (score 0):

Going along with @tek's answer, the only thing different I would do is put my actual query into a stored procedure.

```
create procedure `get_user` (@id int)
as
begin
SELECT user_name FROM users
where user_id = @id
end
```

Then you map that result back to your object. That is just my personal preference to keep the queries with the database instead of in the code.